# How to store blobstore images in the datastore using ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a form which collects the Employee details. I have an option to upload the employee image. I need to store all these data in datastore through ajax. I am using Spring MVC to handle all the requests. I have tried the sample program given in appengine docs using form action. But how to do this operation with ajax?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not start with a simple search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

You asked your question in a very abstract manner, so here is your abstract answer:

1. [Store the images in Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob)
2. The other form elements will be passed as query params to the generated upload URL
3. Once Blobstore/GCS is done processing the upload, it will send a request to the callback route you specified, and that request handler will see a request with all the original params from your form, including a file metadata object.
4. If you want to know how to do a file upload with ajax instead of a form element, check the link provided by the other user in a comment. You can also try google, to learn the particular syntax of sending file uploads from whichever ajax library you're using.